# proving Cartesian product of two metric space is a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I saw somewhere that Cartesian product $X = X_1 \times  X_2$ of two metric spaces $(X_1,d_1)$ and $(X_2,d_2)$ can be made into a metric space $(X,d)$ like following:

$d(x,y) = (d_1(x_1,y_1)^p + d_2(x_2,y_2)^p)^{1/p}$

How do I prove $(X,d)$ is metric space? More specifically, how to prove triangular inequality?

[Note: $p\ge1$, $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y= (y_1,y_2)$]

Comment: the latter part $d_1 d_2$ is it $d_2(x_2, y_2)$?

Comment: yes sir,i corrected it

Comment: "how to prove d(x,y) is metric space?" This is absurd, d(x,y) is a *number*, not a space. // Which axioms defining a metric space are a problem?

Comment: soory i corrected it

Comment: `Which axioms defining a metric space are a problem?`

Comment: There are three axioms you need to check.  Check them, and then you know that it's a metric space.

Comment: triangle inequality.remaining three no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $X_1 = X_2 = \mathbb{R}$. You know how to make a metric on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^2$ out of the metric on $\mathbb{R}$ in a way that looks like the one above (think: Pythagorean theorem). Try and generalize this.